# Socket.io on a multicore server

Tags: websocket, redis, socket.io

I've a node.js socket.io implementation that I need to use all cores on an EC2 Ubuntu instance.

All tutorials / info seems to be about horizontal scaling with Redis etc.  I don't need that, but I do want to use all the cores on the server.

Do I need sticky sessions (e.g. with `sticky-session`) to scale vertically and use all CPU cores?

Comment: Socket.io has a cluster adapter: https://socket.io/docs/v4/cluster-adapter/  but the broad scenario is you'd be better off resorting to pub-sub (as in redis) than relying on sticky sessions alone

Comment: Thank you. Does that apply to a single machine with multiple cores, or only to clusters of multiple machines?  i.e. would I need that to enable multiple CPU cores to be used on one machine?

Comment: single machine, multiple nodejs instances. I haven't tried other layouts